# ng-bootstrap: How to overwrite modal window html

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I'm using ng-bootstrap for my modals. I was wondering what would be the best way to customize the html of the modal window.

By default the modal html looks something like

```
<div role="document" class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    //template or component
  </div>
</div>
```

There are a couple elements that I want in every modal.
I'd like to add those elements to the html generated by ng-bootstrap so I don't have to keep writing them out in a template.

Is there a nice simple way to do this?

Comment: Write a wrapper component to the `ng-bootstrap` modal and add your custom html/css there ?

Comment: I'd like to put extra elements inside the div with class 'modal-dialog' if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom classes via  windowClass: 'myModal'

```
open(content) {
this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title', size: 'sm', backdropClass: 'light-blue-backdrop', windowClass: 'dark-modal'}).result.then((result) => {
  this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
}, (reason) => {
  this.closeResult = 'lol';
});
```

}

For more information and options see: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app/modal-options.ts